# How to mount a drive with read only permission

Tags: ubuntu, fstab

I am using this is fstab to mount the partition at backup.

```
/dev/sda5 /media/virtual ntfs defaults 0 0
```

When i reboot the permissions are automatically set to 777.

I want that only one user i.e userA can read and write , all others should not see the contents of that drive.

What should i do

anything like

```
 /dev/sda5 /media/virtual ntfs userA 700  defaults 0 0
```

Answer (score 1):

/dev/sda5 /media/virtual ntfs defaults,umask=700,uid=1 0 0

change the UID to the appropriate user (found in /etc/passwd). 1 is root.

Comment: That was tricy i had to use 077 to make it work

Comment: I tried that and it works but it is making 700 permission of all the folders inside as well , how can i only make those permissions for one main folder virtual only