# Use NET USE to mount a network drive as read only

Tags: windows, mount, network-share, drive, net-use

I'm using the following code to mount a network drive in a script that configures desktop icons and favorites by copying them when the user logs into windows.

```
NET USE W: \\Server\Files\IT\auto /user:"DOMAIN\username" "password"
```

I have read the question [How to mount a drive with read only permission](https://serverfault.com/questions/140935/how-to-mount-a-drive-with-read-only-permission) but it's asking about linux.

Does anyone know how to mount a network drive as read only via script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to set the permissions on the share such that it only allows read access.  This is something that can be done pretty easily.  If you've got a share right click on the folder, and select properties. 
[image]

Go to the sharing permissions tab and select "permissions" then uncheck all boxes *except* the read box for that user (or group.)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Do it via permissions on the 'server', not only am I not sure you can force it via NET USE (nothing leapt out at me via Google anyway) but why would you want to do it this way?

Comment: Because I don't have access to the server at the moment.  Thanks for the answers.  I'll do it the right way. ;)

Comment: Another reason might be that normally you have write access to the server through that share, but you want to make sure you are not going to change something inadvertently this time. Too bad Windows does not allow this. In Unix you can do mount -r.